# problema plugin camera cordova android

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, plugin

Estou tentando fazer um "Hello World" em cordova, trata-se de uma tela com um botão que aciona a camera, não é necessario fazer nada a mais, basta acionar a camera. 
os passos que segui.

1. cordova create hello com.bruno.hello hello
2. cd hello
3. cordova plataforms add android
4. cordova build
5. npm install cordova-plugin-camera
6. editei o index.html como mostro no trecho abaixo

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function teste(){
       navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
           destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
       });             
     }
     function onSuccess(imageData) {
       var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
       }
      function onFail(message) {
         alert('Failed because: ' + message);
      }
 </script>
  <button onclick="teste(); ">TESTAR</button>
```

7. cordova run android

#### O emulador e carregado com o botão, mas quando aperto, nada acontece

tentei seguir o exemplho do link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.6.1/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html

sem sucesso

> estou usando o Windows 10 64bits

Comment: Uma dúvida, já tentou rodar em um dispositivo real? Tive problemas com o Cordova rodando na máquina virtual da SDK. Plugue o dispositivo, habilite a depuração por USB e tenha os drivers instalados, depois rode **cordova run android**

Comment: @RenanCavalieri tentei sim, porem com o phonegap developer, nao sei se é a mesma coisa, mas rodou o app com o mesmo problema

Comment: Nesse caso então resta saber se você colocou permissões pro seu aplicativo, cheque esses arquivos e veja se possuem as seguintes linhas https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova/camera/camera.html

Comment: @RenanCavalieri isso é no AndroidManifest????

Comment: Sim, apesar dessa documentação estar desatualizada, os caminhos são os mesmos, ao menos eram até a versão 4.0 que foi a qual eu utilizei.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri só possui  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA", como que incluo esta linha la? qual tag eu uso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32436/discussion-between-bruno-gomes-and-renan-cavalieri).

Comment: um detalhe importante, vc pode está usando a documentação de versão diferente à que vc está instalado, certifique-se disso. A mais recente pode ser acessada em : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar o parâmetro Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL use Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI por problemas de memoria já conhecido. ai ficaria assim:

```js
function onSuccess(uriSrc) {
   var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   image.src = uriSrc;
}
```

Comment: exato, eu estou iniciando, e deconhecia a estrutura basica, depois de um tempo maior estudando eu encontrei, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando a versão mais recente do Cordova, verifique no index.html se consta a seguinte linha:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src  *">
```

Esse recurso foi introduzido nas últimas versões, e serve para evitar acessos indesejados ao seu aplicativo. Tive esse mesmo problema, e quando excluí a linha funcionou normalmente.

Nesse link tem uma descrição melhor sobre o assunto:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5